# Bash script to read .csv file to create/move content

Tags: bash, csv

I have a folder containing thousands of images (abc.jpg, 6_08.jpg, refugee_awareness_workshop_by_british_red_cross.jpg etc) and a csv file that contains columnA an ID number (1036, 10028 etc) and column B the image filenames.

Using Automator for Mac I'm going to open a finder file (the .csv) then run a bash script that would create a folder for each ID and move the corresponding image to that folder. A folder can have multiple images.

My bash script so far is:

```
cd "${1%/*}"

while read line         

do         

     FolderName=${line%,*}

     ImageName=${line#*,}

     mkdir "$FolderName"

     mv "$ImageName" "$FolderName"

done < "$1"
```

This seems to create the folders fine but then it returns this error:

**mv: rename abc.jpg\r to 1030/abc.jpg\r: No such file or directory**

And a screenshot of my CSV is as follows:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: `\r` - your input file has dos line endings. Use `dos2unix` to convert  it.

Comment: It looks like you may have some line ending issues in the csv file you are reading lines from (as evident by the `\r` in the error message), You can try to fix it via command line with `tr -d '\r' < old_csv_file > new_csv_file`, which just removes all the `\r` from your file.

Comment: @KamilCuk Wouldn't this result in `1030,abc.jpg1047,ghostpoet.jpg1052,lemn-sissay-something-dark.jpg` which could break?

Comment: `\r` is carriage return character, not a newline `\n`

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of 18-lines of your csv, post the text of 18-lines of your csv (indented by 4-spaces so it formats properly)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove extraneous carriage returns from `ImageName` with:

```
ImageName=$(tr -d '\r' <<< "$ImageName")
```

You may also like to replace:

```
mkdir "$FolderName"
```

with:

```
mkdir -p "$FolderName"
```

because it won't emit errors when called with a directory name that already exists - like you say you have.